# Looking for a java library automate third party Java-Swing application without access to the source code

Tags: java, testng, uiautomation

I'm looking to automate a third party java swing application that my company uses. I don't have access to it's source code so a lot of the swing testing libraries like Assert-J won't work. I'd like to integrate the tests into my existing TestNG framework that houses our Selenium and API tests and is integrated into our SDLC systems. Any recommendations?

Comment: What have you tried so far? My gut says you can't beat "point and click" ones that control the mouse and keyboard directly, but I don't have enough familiarity with it to formulate an answer.

Comment: For UI automation you have some commercial tools which support Swing -> QF-Test and Ranorex.